# PHP: get weekday number of the month

Tags: php, date, timestamp, strtotime

I'm looking for functionality that would do the opposite of

```
strtotime("third monday");
```

i.e. a function that is fed a timestamp and would return the weekday number of the month.

So if today is 18.07.2016, ideally the function should return "3" (i.e. 3rd Monday of July).

I can get the weekday itself by using date("D", [timestamp]), but I'm not sure how to calculate that it is in fact the third one this month.

Has anyone tried doing anything like this before?

Comment: It's not as complicated as you think. The answer is independent of the specific weekday. That is, the 7th of the month is always the 1st something and the 8th of the month is always the 2nd something, etc. So you basically divide by 7. See mister martin's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to verify you're working within a valid date range, but this is a relatively simple task:

```
$today = date('d', time());
echo 1 + floor(($today - 1) / 7); // nth day of month
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the Carbon class. It expands date and time functions to basically everything you'd ever need, including human-readable timestamps (ie. "5 minutes ago")

These two would be useful to you - the day and week of the month.

```
var_dump($dt->dayOfWeek);                                    // int(3)

var_dump($dt->weekOfMonth);                                  // int(1)
```

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters

Comment: It appears to be a one-liner anyway: `return (int) ceil($this->day / static::DAYS_PER_WEEK);`